# Excel 2010 recomended charts

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a chart in excel 2010.

Usually when I do this I just highlight the data and select: `Insert` and then `Recommended chart`
However the `Recommended chart` option is not showing up now.

Anyone have any idea why this may have disappeared?

Thanks!

Comment: Add an example of the data you are selecting.

Answer (score 2):

Recommended Charts was added as a feature of Excel 2013, there is no related command or chart wizard in Excel 2010.

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Whats-new-in-Excel-2013-1cbc42cd-bfaf-43d7-9031-5688ef1392fd